How can I efficiently retrieve filtered rows from this PostgreSQL table?
I have a PostgreSQL table with almost 9 million rows, and am finding that when I filter on a foreign key I get dramatically different query times depending on how far through the index the database needs to dig. For example:
SELECT id FROM log WHERE fk_id = 123 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;

can execute in 0.05 seconds if the first matching rows have IDs in the 8-9 million range, but can take 3-4 minutes if the IDs are between 6-7 million. And if I change DESC to ASC the query time unsurprisingly seems to favour lower ID results.
If I run EXPLAIN (analyze, verbose, buffers) on the query, I get:
 Limit  (cost=0.43..2258.76 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=47208.015..47208.017 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: id
   Buffers: shared hit=477301 read=502061 written=1
   ->  Index Scan Backward using log_pkey on public.log  (cost=0.43..3814302.94 rows=1689 width=4) (actual time=47208.011..47208.011 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: id
         Filter: (log.fk_id = 6136)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2483252
         Buffers: shared hit=477301 read=502061 written=1
 Planning time: 0.123 ms
 Execution time: 47208.041 ms

and with ASC it's the same without Backward.
The fk is "fk_id_refs_id" FOREIGN KEY (fk_id) REFERENCES fk_table(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
The indexes in question are:
"log_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"log_fk_id" btree (fk_id)

What strategies could I employ to allow such SELECT queries to perform efficiently on a table like this?
If it helps, this is on an old server running PostgreSQL 9.5 (!). shared_buffers = 128MB which is perhaps way too low for the 8GB RAM available? work_mem and effective_cache_size have not been explicitly set so must be adopting default values. 8 CPUs, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz, 20MB L3 cache.

UPDATES:
After Frank Heikens suggestions below I increased shared_buffers to 2GB and added CREATE INDEX "log_id_fk_id_idx" ON "log" ("id", "fk_id");
I may have oversimplified my example -- in the super-long running queries, I realised I'm actually looking up the foreign key in a list of possible IDs, not just one like I showed above, if I run EXPLAIN on that query now I get this:
 Limit  (cost=0.43..1314.57 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=4346.122..12149.772 rows=100 loops=1)
   Output: id
   Buffers: shared hit=1112029 read=31955
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using log_id_fk_id_idx on public.log  (cost=0.43..1046435.72 rows=79629 width=4) (actual time=4346.120..12149.580 rows=100 loops=1)
         Output: id
         Filter: (log.fk_id = ANY ('{8076,6993,6693,6442,6136,5772,3861,3526,3343,2928,2927,2324,1918,1806,1803,1628,1619,1439,1436,1435,1434,1398,1365,1146,1081,1062,970,941,932,863,844,837,783,482,481,480,479,468,452,396,378,347,340,338,230,229,227}'::integer[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 7349924
         Heap Fetches: 240040
         Buffers: shared hit=1112029 read=31955
 Planning time: 0.302 ms
 Execution time: 12149.891 ms

is there a special kind of index I can use for optimising queries on a list of IDs like the above?
and if I SELECT * rather than SELECT ID I get this:
 Limit  (cost=0.43..5413.56 rows=100 width=878) (actual time=86936.151..395438.045 rows=100 loops=1)
   Output: id, fk_id, other_fields_go_here
   Buffers: shared hit=1585734 read=1609164 written=1
   ->  Index Scan Backward using log_pkey on public.log  (cost=0.43..4310421.37 rows=79629 width=878) (actual time=86936.148..395437.789 rows=100 loops=1)
         Output: id, fk_id, other_fields_go_here
         Filter: (log.fk_id = ANY ('{8076,6993,6693,6442,6136,5772,3861,3526,3343,2928,2927,2324,1918,1806,1803,1628,1619,1439,1436,1435,1434,1398,1365,1146,1081,1062,970,941,932,863,844,837,783,482,481,480,479,468,452,396,378,347,340,338,230,229,227}'::integer[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 7349928
         Buffers: shared hit=1585734 read=1609164 written=1
 Planning time: 0.537 ms
 Execution time: 395438.197 ms

which is 32x slower execution time than just querying ID, and doesn't use the new combined id/fk_id index, presumably because it was able to use Index Only Scan when I was asking for only columns contained in the index itself. I can limit the number of fields queried somewhat, but do need quite a few of them, so won't be able to use an Index Only Scan to get the data I need

Version 9.5? That's EOL for over 3 years. I would spend my time on upgrading to a supported version. And that could also solve your performance problem. A quick fix might be an index on the combination of these two columns.

By the way, shared_buffers is very very low. Try 2GB, 25% of the system.

You shouldn't expect high performance if you are using IN (aka = ANY). Alternatively, if the set is alyways limited in size (less than 10 values) you could use Dynamic SQL to get blazing fast performance by union-ing multiple seeks.
